# TLS Version 1.0 Protocol Detection

Tags: asp.net, tls1.2

TLS Version 1.0 Protocol Detected in Tenable Scan. The remote service encrypts traffic using an older version of TLS on target groups, where Dot Net 6.0 version API program was installed.
We have a Application Load Balancer which have Target group, where Linux OS installed.
We changed the security Policy of Load Balancer to use TLS13-1-2-2021-06 to allow only TLS1.2 and TLS1.3.
even in the scan, we get the same vulnerability. Solution provided as to enable TLS1.2 and/orTLS1.3 and disable TLS1.1.

Tried changing the security policy in ALB, but no luck.

Can someone help on this.